# kafka records aren't being deleted

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to delete kafka records from a topic by doing below:

```
bin/kafka-delete-records.sh --bootstrap-server myserver:myport --offset-json-file offset.json
```

my offset.json looks like this:

```
{"partitions": [{"topic": "mytopic", "partition": 0, "offset": 127}], "version":1}
```

When I run the script I get the message below:

```
➜  local-kafka_2.12-2.0.0 bin/kafka-delete-records.sh --bootstrap-server myip:myport --offset-json-file offset.json
Executing records delete operation
Records delete operation completed:
[2019-02-02 16:54:24,867] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
partition: mytopic-0  error: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
```

I'm noticing that the records aren't actually deleted when I run the `kafka-consumer-group.sh`

My configs are as below:

[image]

**Question**

- What am I missing. Why aren't the kafka records from the topics deleting?

Comment: You got the following warning: "Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available."

Comment: Can you consume messages from `mytopic`? Check that your broker is up. Also, Be sure of misspelling.

Comment: What are you expecting to see exactly in `kafka-consumer-group`? The `delete-records` command deletes all messages before an offset... It won't "reduce" those offset numbers